# Android resource linking failed activity_main.xml:19: error: attribute android:defaultNavHost not found after adding navigation components

Tags: android, attributes, androidx, android-architecture-navigation

Recently I have been pretty much excited about new exciting android tools. Among them Navigation literialy hooked me up. I thought this [code lab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-navigation/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Findex#2) would be wonderful to get started. Nonetheless, as an absolute beginner I found it a bit intriguing as it didn't state anything about step-by-step of setting up navigation components. So I started to break it up into bite sized section and start implementing it into a separate project.

My main activity code

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
}

override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean =
  findNavController(R.id.my_nav_host_fragment).navigateUp()
}
```

in my main activity layout

```
<fragment
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="0dp"
  android:layout_weight="1"
  android:id="@+id/my_nav_host_fragment"
  android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
  android:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation"
  android:defaultNavHost="true"
  />
```

after this log shows error[image]

Comment: Make sure you have added `app:startDestination="@id/homeFragment"` in your **navigation.xml** file

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your error is explicitly self-explanative

> Android resource linking failed activity_main.xml:19: error: attribute android:defaultNavHost not found

The reason is You wrote the wrong attribute `android:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation"
  android:defaultNavHost="true"` which should be `app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation"
  app:defaultNavHost="true"`

if you edit these attributes you will see your project build successfully and in your navigation graph file shows as the default navigation host[image], hope it does answer your question.

Answer (score 2):

In case you have already provided correct attributes; ie;

```
app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation"
app:defaultNavHost="true"
```

& you are still getting this error, follow below steps:

1. In Project build.gradle :

   dependencies {
         classpath "androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:2.2.1"
    }
2. In app build.gradle :

   def nav_version = "2.2.2"

   implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$nav_version"

   implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:$nav_version"